# Generic string trimming trigger for Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, triggers

Problem:

One of the owners of the company that I work for has direct database access. He uses Navicat on a windows notebook. Apparently, it has a feature that he likes where he can import data from Excel. The problem is that text fields often (or maybe always) end up with a \r\n at the end of them. Which can lead to display, reporting and filtering issues. I've been asked to clean this up and to stop him from doing it.

I know I can just add a trigger to each table that will do something like:

```
NEW.customer_name := regexp_replace(NEW.customer_name, '\r\n', '', 'g');
```

However, I would prefer to not write a separate trigger function for each table that he has access to (there are over 100). My idea was to just write a generic function and then pass in an array of column names I want corrected via the `TG_ARGV[]` argument.

Is there a way to update a triggers `NEW` record dynamically based on the TG_ARGV array?

Details:

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.6.6 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no native means to dynamically access the columns of the `new` record in a plpgsql trigger function. The only way I know is to convert the record to jsonb, modify it and convert it back to record using `jsonb_populate_record()`:

```
create or replace function a_trigger()
returns trigger language plpgsql as $$
declare
    j jsonb = to_jsonb(new);
    arg text;
begin
    foreach arg in array tg_argv loop
        if j->>arg is not null then
            j = j || jsonb_build_object(arg, regexp_replace(j->>arg, e'\r\n', '', 'g'));
        end if;
    end loop;
    new = jsonb_populate_record(new, j);
    return new;
end;
$$;
```

The case is much simpler if you can [use plpython:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpython-trigger.html)

```
create or replace function a_trigger()
returns trigger language plpython3u as $$
    import re
    new = TD["new"]
    for col in TD["args"]:
        new[col] = re.sub(r"\r\n", "", new[col])
    return "MODIFY"
$$;
```

Comment: Hmmm...  I do have the uplpython extension installed on the box. Would be interesting to see which is faster. I'll run a few tests and post my very rough and unscientific benchmarks.

Comment: Simpler not always means faster. I expect python would be a bit faster but the difference should not be great.

Comment: TD["args"] is a list of function arguments, not a list of columns, right?

Comment: @Tudor - right. The OP's idea is *to just write a generic function and then pass in an array of column names (...) via the TG_ARGV[] argument.*

Comment: Sorry I wan't specific: you have a typo in the ``for col in TD["args"]:`` as it should be ``for col in new``, right? Thanks

Comment: @Tudor - no, `TD["args"]` is an array of column names passed as arguments. The code is correct as is.

Comment: oh.. ok, for me it didn't work as I hadn't pass any arguments, I expected it to clean any tabe on which the trigger is on; I did a ``for col in new:`` followed by an ``if type(new[col]) == str:`` to modify all the text columns. Thanks for replying.